# jquery not(:contains) not working with nested html table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a nested HTML table where column 4 is a nested HTML table.

I am filtering the records based on a criteria provided and coloring the invalid records red.

This jquery solution works well when I remove the nested HTML table but with HTML table inside a TD it seems to be not working.

Can someone please suggest why? Any help will be appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmrbknf8/)

```
<div id="divQualCodeFuncPMType">
    <table class="SetDWPParameterTabStyle">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="GridHeaderSystemParamter">
                <td>
                    Map Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    Type Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    Material Type
                </td>
                <td>
                    Attributes
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label1">10</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label2">60</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label3">Paper</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label4">80% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label5">20% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label6">20</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label7">70</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label8">Box</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label9">60% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label10">40% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label11">20</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label12">70</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label13">Wood</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label14">80% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Label15">20% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span1">20</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span2">70</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span3">Wood</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Span4">80% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Span5">20% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span6">20</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span7">70</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Span8">Wood</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Span9">80% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="Span10">20% cotton</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
var x = "Box";
var y = "80";
var $el = $('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0)').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:nth-child(3) span:not(:contains("' + x + '"))').length || $(this).find('td:nth-child(4) span:not(:contains("' + y + '"))').length;
});
$el.css("color", "red");
```

Comment: what is the condition you are looking for.... do you want to color rows which does not have `Box` in `td:nth-child(3)` or `80` in `td:nth-child(4)` so only second row should be left out?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am looking for the condition that color all records which does not have Box in column 3 and 80 in column 4, so only 2nd row should be left out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmrbknf8/4/ ?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3noopv2/ and the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use more specific selector rule - child selector instead of descendant.

You should iterate over only the direct `tr` children of the outer table, not the `tr`s of inner table so should not use descendant selector for the `tr` element.

```js
var x = "Box";
var y = "80";
var $el = $('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table > tbody > tr:gt(0)').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).find('td:nth-child(3) span:contains("' + x + '")').length || !$(this).find('> td:nth-child(4) span:contains("' + y + '")').length;
});
$el.css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divQualCodeFuncPMType">
  <table class="SetDWPParameterTabStyle">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="GridHeaderSystemParamter">
        <td>
          Map Id
        </td>
        <td>
          Type Id
        </td>
        <td>
          Material Type
        </td>
        <td>
          Attributes
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="Label1">10</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label2">60</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label3">Paper</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label4">80% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label5">20% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="Label6">20</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label7">70</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label8">Box</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label9">60% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label10">40% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="Label11">30</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label12">80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Label13">Wood</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label14">80% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Label15">20% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="Span1">40</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Span2">90</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Span3">Tin</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Span4">30% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Span5">70% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="Span6">50</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Span7">50</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="Span8">Box</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Span9">80% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span id="Span10">20% cotton</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using descendant selectors and not immediate children:

e.g.

```
> table tbody tr:gt(0)
```

instead of

```
> table > tbody > tr:gt(0)
```

Otherwise it will include all first rows in any tbody in any descendants etc.

The same applies to

```
td:nth-child(3) span:not(:contains("' + x + '"))
```

which should be

```
> td:nth-child(3) > span:not(:contains("' + x + '"))
```

and also the last selector:

```
> td:nth-child(4) span:not(:contains("' + y + '"))
```

needs to be

```
> td:nth-child(4) > span:not(:contains("' + y + '"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vmrbknf8/5/

Comment: you helped me last time as well with the similar issue. I have updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vmrbknf8/2/ ) but does not seem to be working :-(

Comment: You needed to do it to the last selector as well: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vmrbknf8/5/

Comment: In your jsfiddle its has colored two rows having box but condition says Box + 80 so only last row should have not been colored